# Difference between GLP_DUAL and GLP_DUALP in GLPK method

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, glpk

I will really appreciate if any one help me to know the difference between GLP_DUAL and GLP_DUALP in GLPK method.

Answer (score 1):

`GLP_DUALP` falls back to primal simplex if dual fails, quoting the source:

```
#define GLP_DUALP          2  /* use dual; if it fails, use primal */
#define GLP_DUAL           3  /* use dual simplex */
```